# How to Open Excel File with JavaFX

Tags: java, excel, javafx

I'm making a project in which the user has to give in a document with data. The program reads the data and makes some diagrams. It al works perfectly but i want to open the ExcelFile when the user has saved it...So I know the directory of the Excelfile but i don't know how to open an excelfile in javaFX, can someone help me?

kind regards

Comment: Can you clarify? Are you wanting to read the contents of an Excel file with Java code, or create an Excel file with Java code? Or do you just have an existing Excel file that you want to automatically open with Excel?

Comment: I want to open an existing file with excel :)

Comment: @MiLo Desktop.getDesktop().edit(File path); should do it

Comment: will Desktop.getDesktop().open(File path) do the job?

Comment: You should use the JavaFX way to do this, not the AWT way. Putting together an answer...

Comment: @MiLo as James_D said: use the javaFx way (didn't know that there is such a thing)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The JavaFX way to do this is

```
File excelFile = new File("/path/to/excel/file");
getHostServices().showDocument(excelFile.toURI().toURL().toExternalForm());
```

`getHostServices()` is defined in `Application`, so if you want to do this in another class (a controller, for example), you will have to arrange for the other class to be able to access the host services.

E.g.

```
public class MyApp extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(...);
        Parent root = loader.load();
        MyController controller = loader.getController();
        controller.setHostServices(getHostServices());
        //... setup and show scene and stage...
    }
}
```

With the obvious method in the controller and the code above suitably modified.

Comment: nice. Didn't know that ther is a javaFx way to open a Document. Thx a lot for that answer!

Comment: @James_D this answer works well for loading fxml directly from start method of Application class. But what if we want to use HostServices later in the application? I am a bit new to SO, not sure whether its ok to ask here or I have to ask a separate question?